# How to make checkboxs selected from apex code

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want that when I am binding by checkboxs at that time only based on condition I can make checkbox by default selected or unselected.
VF PAGE:

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!wrapItemslist}"  layout="pageDirection" >
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!ChkboxItems}"/>                      
   </apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

APEX CONTROLLER CODE:

```
public List<String> wrapItemslist {get; set;}
public List<SelectOption> getChkboxItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();           
    for(lovel__Item__c i: getitms()){
        boolean x =false; // By default make flag false
        for(lovel__Item_Manufacture_Mapper__c imm: [SELECT lovel__Item__c FROM lovel__Item_Manufacture_Mapper__c WHERE lovel__Manufacturer__c = :id]){
            if(i.Id == imm.lovel__Item__c) {
                x=true; /* Making Flag True and if flag true then make   checkbox selected  */
            }                 
        }
        options.add(new SelectOption(i.Id,i.Name,x));
    }
    return options;
}
```

Comment: can you share your visualforce? Lists of SelectOptions is not usually used to support checkboxes..

Comment: Done what you were needing.  All I am needing that how can I make checkboxs option selected from apex code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here it is an example.

If you want to make some of checkboxes selected by default just add value to the field which is used in

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!selectedCheckbox}">
```

In your code it is `wrapItemslist`

Also using SOQL FOR in most cases it is a good idea, but using it inside another loop is wrong.

ApexController:

```
public with sharing class SelectCheckboxesController {

public List<String> selectedCheckbox { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption> checkboxOptions { get; set; }

public SelectCheckboxesController() {
    List<Account> accounts = [
        SELECT Id, Name
        FROM Account
        LIMIT 10
    ];
    this.selectedCheckbox = new List<String>();
    this.checkboxOptions = new List<SelectOption>();

    for (Account aAccount : accounts) {
        checkboxOptions.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(aAccount.Id), aAccount.Name));
        //MAKE SELECT BY DEFAULT
        if (aAccount.Name.contains('United')) {
            selectedCheckbox.add(aAccount.Id);
        }
    }
}

public void saveAction() {
    SYSTEM.DEBUG('AAAAAA selectedCheckbox \n\n ' + selectedCheckbox);
}
```

}

ApexPage:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="SelectCheckboxesController">

<apex:form >
    <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!selectedCheckbox}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!checkboxOptions}"/>
    </apex:selectCheckboxes>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveAction}" />
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Super this solved my both the issues thanks a lot and never I thought this would be so damn easy I was complicating the the things so much.

Answer (score 1):

The collection of id's that are selected is captured in `wrapItemslist`. In order to get the checked items preset before loading the page, you need to populate this list with the right id's.

However, right now it's a list of String while the SelectOption identifier is an Id. So you have to slightly change your code in 2 places: make the list a list of Id, and adding the selected Id's to the list.

```
public List<Id> wrapItemslist {get; set;}
public List<SelectOption> getChkboxItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();           
    for(lovel__Item__c i: getitms()){
        boolean x =false; // By default make flag false
        for(lovel__Item_Manufacture_Mapper__c imm: [SELECT lovel__Item__c FROM lovel__Item_Manufacture_Mapper__c WHERE lovel__Manufacturer__c = :id]){
            if(i.Id == imm.lovel__Item__c) {
                wrapItemslist.add(i.Id); /* Adding Id to list of selected records, to make checkbox selected  */
            }                 
        }
        options.add(new SelectOption(i.Id,i.Name,x));
    }
    return options;
}
```

> Also you are doing a SOQL query inside of a loop, which is not good
>   coding. I'm answering your selectbox question here but would strongly
>   advise to re-architecture the code to take the query out of the loop.

Comment: I know but I have requirement in which there are three objects 1. Which have list of manufactures 2. Will have list of Items 3. Which will map which Item is manufactured by whom. So when I add Manufacture I want to select items which he/she makes. So when I edit the page at that time also from database it should fetch all the item which manufacture has already selected which checked checkbox and other with unchecked checkbox, so how can I meet up this requirement. So for now all I want is to get all checkbox checked from controller which I am not able to do. Then will take care of nested query

Comment: That's quite  a vague comment if I may say so. If you have an additional or different requirement, you should post it in your question..

Comment: What vague. ? I have mentioned all what I need  !

Comment: I think my answer explains how to check the checkbox for the items that are selected. So let me know if that works for you.